# Robust Standard Errors in spatial error models

Tags: spatial, r-sf, spdep, geostatistics, spatial-regression

I am fitting a Spatial Error Model using the [errorsarlm()](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/spdep/versions/0.2-9/topics/errorsarlm) function in the [spdep](https://r-spatial.github.io/spdep/) library.
The Breusch-Pagan test for spatial models, calculated using the [bptest.sarlm()](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/spdep/versions/1.0-2/topics/bptest.sarlm) function, suggest the presence of heteroskedasticity.

A natural next step would be to get the robust standard error estimates and update the p-values. In the documentation of the [bptest.sarlm()](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/spdep/versions/1.0-2/topics/bptest.sarlm) function says the following:

> "It is also technically possible to make heteroskedasticity corrections to standard error estimates by using the “lm.target” component of sarlm objects - using functions in the lmtest and sandwich packages."

and the following code (as reference) is presented:

```
lm.target <- lm(error.col$tary ~ error.col$tarX - 1)
if (require(lmtest) && require(sandwich)) {
  print(coeftest(lm.target, vcov=vcovHC(lm.target, type="HC0"), df=Inf))}
```

where **error.col** is the spatial error model estimated.

Now, I can easily adapt the code to my problem and get the robust standard errors.
Nevertheless, I was wondering:

- What exactly is the “lm.target” component of sarlm objects? I can not find any mention to it in the spdep documentation.
- What exactly are $tary and $tarX? Again, it does not seem to be mentioned on the documentation.
- Why documentation says it is "**technically possible** to make heteroskedasticity corrections"? Does it mean that proposed approach is not really recommended to overcome issues of heteroskedasticity?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I report this issue on github and had a [response by Roger Bivand:](https://github.com/r-spatial/spatialreg/issues/25)

> No, the approach is not recommended at all. Either use sphet or a Bayesian approach giving the marginal posterior distribution. I'll drop the confusing documentation. tary is $y - \rho W y$ and similarly for tarX in the spatial error model case. Note that tary etc. only occur in spdep in documentation for localmoran.exact() and localmoran.sad(); were you using out of date package versions?